# What are the benefits of chanting the Shiva Mahimna Strotram?

Tags: shiva, prayer, stotra, shiva-mahimna-stotra

Pushhpadanta was a Gandharva singer, in the court of Indra{the Lord of Heaven}.It is said that Pushhpadanta composed a prayer praising the greatness of Lord Shiva.

This prayer later became well known as the Shiva Mahimna Strotram.Many scholars have expressed their adoration for Lord Shiva with poetic and devotional verses.But,among all the Strotras(hymns of praise), the one created and composed by Gandharva Pushhpadanta is believed to be  one of the most popular.

What is the story behind the composition of this prayer by the Gandharva Pushhpadanta?

What  are the benefits of chanting the Shiva Mahimna Strotram?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **Shiva Mahimna Stotra ( शिवमहिम्न)** is very popular among the devotees of Lord Shiva and is considered one of the best among all Stotras in offered  Lord Shiva stotras .

**The legend behind composition of this Stotra is as follows-:**

> Once a
>   king named Chitraratha (चित्ररथ) had made a nice garden with beautiful
>   flowers in it. Those flowers were used every day by  Chitraratha 
>   in worshipping Lord Shiva.   One day a **Gandharva** named **Pushhpadanta**
>   being attracted  by the beautiful flowers, started to steal them, due
>   to this  Chitraratha could not offer flowers to Lord Shiva . He tried 
>   to capture the thief, but failed  because of the Gandharvas having 
>   power to stay invisible.   So Chitraratha spread the Shiva
>   Nirmaalya (flowers left after puja, generally of last day) in his garden . Shiva Nirmaalya  consists of the Bilva
>   leaves, flowers, et cetera which have been used in worshipping Lord
>   Shiva .    The thief Pushhpadanta, not knowing this, walked on the
>   Shiva Nirmaalya, and as this is holy ,  so that he incurred the wrath
>   of Lord Shiva and lost the divine power of invisibility . He then
>   designed a prayer to Lord Shiva for forgiveness. In this prayer he
>   sung the greatness of the Lord.

This very prayer became well known as the `Shiva Mahimna Stotra'. Lord Shiva became pleased by this StotraM, and returned Pushhpadanta's divine powers.[Shiv Mahimna stotra](http://www.speakingtree.in/blog/shiva-mahimna-stotram-with-lyrics-and-meaning)

Download Shiv Mahimna stotra PDF -  [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.harekrsna.de/shiva/Shiva-Mahimna-Stotra.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiOp9r9raHPAhVGsI8KHSfWAGYQFgg6MAg&usg=AFQjCNGfs7_QU4un1rVndpmqFwGTXfuyew&sig2=AuCssHLcsR1Wc5F1CnGruw)

**Benifits of chanting Shiv-Mahimna stotra-:**

> श्री पुष्पदन्त-मुख-पङ्कज-निर्गतेन
>
> स्तोत्रेण किल्बिष-हरेण हर-प्रियेण।
>
> कण्ठस्थितेन पठितेन समाहितेन
>
> सुप्रीणितो भवति भूतपतिर्महेशः॥ ४३॥
>
> This hymn which is dear to Shiva, has emerged out of the lotus-like
>   mouth of Pushhpadanta and is **capable of removing all sins** . May the
>   lord of all beings become greatly pleased with anyone who has learnt
>   this by heart and/or reads or recalls this with
>   single-mindedness.            (43)

Answer (score 6):

Although 1 of the post already answer this Question I am appending few more benefits mentioned in the Shiva Mahimna Strotram itself.

> एककालं द्विकालं वा त्रिकालं यः पठेन्नरः। सर्वपाप-विनिर्मुक्तः शिव लोके
>   महीयते॥

Here **2 benefits** are mentioned-: 
1. Whoever reads Shiva Mahimna Strotram once, twice or thrice (in a day) revels in the domain of Shiva.
2. Whoever reads Shiva Mahimna Strotram once, twice or thrice (in a day) will be bereft of all his/her sins

Another place where similar benefit mentioned is below

> सुरगुरुमभिपूज्य स्वर्ग-मोक्षैक-हेतुं पठति यदि मनुष्यः
>   प्राञ्जलिर्नान्य-चेताः। व्रजति शिव-समीपं किन्नरैः स्तूयमानः
>   स्तवनमिदममोघं पुष्पदन्तप्रणीतम्‌॥

Meaning : If an aspirant for heaven and liberation, worships Shiva,the teacher of gods, at first a**nd then reads this unfailing hymn, composed by Pushhpadanta, with folded hands and single-mindedness, he attains Shiva's abode**, being praised by `kinnaras